# Why are subprocess results different with Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, subprocess

I am trying to understand the behaviour of the `subprocess` module when it is running on a Jupyter notebook on linux. I am using `subprocess` to capture the number of open files limit on Linux. On the terminal this is as follows:

```
ulimit -n
```

This gives me a limit of 1024.

If I call this using `subprocess` from Python on the command line, I still get 1024, as expected:

```
from subprocess import call
call("ulimit -n", shell = True)
```

However, if I run this from a Jupyter notebook, I get 4096.

The same also holds if I use the `resource` module to find out the soft limit. The following gives me 1024 from the command line, but 4096 from a Jupyter notebook.

```
import resource
soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
soft
```

My (possibly naive) assumption is that `subprocess.call` should give me the same results regardless of where I am calling it from. Can anyone explain what causes the difference?

Comment: There may be a difference between the `ulimit` for a terminal and for a browser on your machine, that could explain why.

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560734). that might help checking if it's the case.

Comment: Thanks. That's a possibility. Though if I use prlimit with the pid for the running chrome sessions, it gives me a soft limit of 1024 files, which would suggest that's not what is going on.